# For $\frac{1}{x}u_x+u_y=0$, what is the characteristic equation corresponding to $\frac{1}{x}$?

Tags: partial-differential-equations

For $\frac{1}{x}u_x+u_y=0$, what is the characteristic equation corresponding to $\frac{1}{x}$?

I'm confused, because by this (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_of_characteristics) it should be:

$$\frac{dx}{a(x,y,u)}=\frac{dx}{\frac{1}{x}}=xdx$$

But I believe it should be

$$\text{something}=\frac{1}{x}$$

These are two different equations, so which one is right?

Comment: You forgot $\frac{dy}{\beta(x,y,z)}$. In this PDE $\beta(x,y,z)=1$.

Comment: I changed $a(x,y,z) \to a(x,y,u)$ I think it was a typo, please check it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\frac{1}{x}u_x+u_y=0$$
$$\frac{dx}{\frac{1}{x}}=\frac{dy}{1}=\frac{du}{0}$$
First characteristics curves : $\quad du=0\quad\to\quad u=c_1$

Second characteristics curves : $\quad xdx=dy \quad\to\quad 2y-x^2=c_2$

General solution of the PDE :
$$u=f(2y-x^2)$$
$f$ is an arbitrary function.

This is the same result as MrYouMath's result. But the symbols $f$ and $F$ are for different functions $f(2X)=F(X)$, which doesn't matter since whose functions are arbitrary : $u=f(2y-x^2)=F(y-\frac{1}{2}x^2)$.

Answer (score 1):

By the method of characteristics you obtain:

$$\dfrac{dx}{d\tau}=1/x$$
$$\dfrac{dy}{d\tau}=1$$
$$\dfrac{du}{d\tau}=0.$$

Dividing the first two equations you obtain: 
$$dy/dx = x \implies dy=xdx \implies y = 1/2x^2+c_2 \implies c_2=y-1/2x^2.$$
From the last equation you obtain $du=0 \implies u = c_1=c_1(c_2)=c_1(y-1/2x^2).$

Hence, the solution $u(x,y)=F(y-1/2x^2)$.

Comment: What's $\tau$? Are you using a curve parametrization?

Comment: Yes, but by dividing the equations you can eliminate $\tau$ as a parameter.